# ERROR: Package 'object-detection' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>3.6'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to install tensorflow-object-detection API.  Installed Tensorflow-gpu-2.1.0   already  with  pip.

```
sudo python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver tensorflow-gpu
```

But when trying to install tensorflow-object-detection-api I am getting this error :  ERROR: Package 'object-detection' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>3.6'

Same with python3 :   ERROR: Package 'object-detection' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>3.6'

The error is shown when running the following command in the installation step :

```
python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

O.S  :  Ubuntu 16.04

Python: 2.7.12

Comment: the error messages are very clear in what the issue is, you need a Python version greater than 3.6

Comment: I guess it's time to forget about Python 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty plain.

You're attempting to use a package which requires Python 3.6 with Python 2.7 (which is end-of-life [since January 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)), and then with Python 3.5 (which is end-of-life [tomorrow, at the end of September 2020](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3510/)).

Upgrade your system to a newer Python; 3.8 is the current version.